# How to I upload a file to Amazon S3 server through PHP?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, cdn

I am trying to use the following REST client to upload files to Amazon S3:
https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class

I am having trouble with it, though.

Through my terminal I can upload files like with the following command:

```
$cmd = "s3cmd put --acl-public --guess-mime-type " . $loc . " s3://censored/static/images/" . $filename;
```

I cannot actually run this using exec or shell_exec, though, so I am using the above REST client. Here is what I am trying to do, but it does not seem to work:

```
if ($s3->putObject($loc, "s3://censored/static/images/", $filename, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ)) {
  echo "File Uploaded.";
} else {
  echo "Failed to upload file.";
}
```

The above always fails, and I am not sure why. I would like to think it is because the I am not writing out the bucket directory string correctly because I am able to do s3->listBuckets() successfully. `$loc` is the location on my hard drive of the file I want to upload to the S3 server. `$filename` is the name that I want to call the uploaded file on the s3 server.

Comment: Have you looked at [the example](https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class/blob/master/example.php)? It clearly shows you how to achieve this.

Comment: One thing: 1. How do I deal with buckets with more depth? The example only looks at uploading a file to a parent bucket. That is where I am having problems. I have a full s3:// path, but they are just giving a bucket. How would I give a path to a child bucket?